# Динамическая смена картинки

Tags: html

Как сделать на html так, чтобы при нажатии на картинку сайт оставался тем же а картинки менялись?

Comment: а что это за кнопки, которые сами нажимают на картинки? новшества CSS3?))

Comment: Да человек из будущего пишет, там уже HTML 10, CSS 5, IE 13, У них там не только кнопка на картинки нажимает и "сайт оставляется тем же, а картинки меняются"))

Comment: @Expert не сильно помог своей правкой. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется тут надо использовать Frame, или тут дело за javascript